# LinearLayout getChildAt works different in Nougat

Tags: android, android-layout

I've this layout as first child of a TableRow:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/BodyAllegati"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65" 
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/locGpsIcon"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/BodySegnalini"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need to get the most inner linear layout (the one after the ImageView).

I did in the following way:

```
LinearLayout colAll = (LinearLayout) r.getChildAt(0); // outer l.layout (r is the TableRow)
LinearLayout colAllChild = (LinearLayout) colAll.getChildAt(0); // first inner l.layout
LinearLayout colSeg = (LinearLayout) colAllChild.getChildAt(1); // l.layout after the ImageView
```

It happens that all works correctly in older Android versions. If i run the app in Android 7, colSeg is null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have two layout that one in layout-v24 and you forget add layout in it.
so you must add changes in both layouts

Comment: that happens to me too . it is a bad bad mistake